# Incorrect behavior of getArgs on Windows under cygwin

Tags: windows, haskell, command-line, cygwin

I'm trying to pass an asterisk symbol in quotes into my console app as a command line argument, and when I get it using `System.Environment.getArgs`, I actually get list of files in current directory. This is wrong, because I wrap asterisk into quotes, so text in quotes shouldn't be substituted. How do I get command line arguments without such substitution in Windows under cygwin?

Comment: This seems more like a windows' issue than Haskell's.

Comment: Are you using single quotes or double quotes?

Comment: That's an issue with your shell, not with `getArgs`. Globbing is performed before any arguments are sent to your program.

Comment: @valderman That's not necessarily true on Windows, where programs are expected to perform glob-expansion themselves (`cmd.exe` does not expand globs and [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx) is just a single string; the C runtime parses that before entering `main`).

Comment: Oh. I guess I've been stuck in *nix-land a wee bit too long, to forget that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enclose it in single quotes, `'*'` it doesn't get expanded, but the two inverted commas get through into the result of `getArgs` (see below), so you'd need to remove them later.

The reason `"*"` is expanded in windows is that inverted commas are legitimate as part of a globbable filename , because of spaces. You might want to `del "temp file *.dat"` at some point.

```
module ListArgs where
 import System.Environment
 main = getArgs >>= print
```

gives:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling ListArgs             ( ListArgs.hs, ListArgs.o )
Linking ListArgs.exe ...

D:\Files\Andrew\prog\haskell\utils>ListArgs.exe *
["HereDoc.hs","IOutils.lhs","SugaredApplicative.hs","ListArgs.exe","ListArgs.hi","ListArgs.hs","ListArgs.o"]

D:\Files\Andrew\prog\haskell\utils>ListArgs.exe "*"
["HereDoc.hs","IOutils.lhs","SugaredApplicative.hs","ListArgs.exe","ListArgs.hi","ListArgs.hs","ListArgs.o"]

D:\Files\Andrew\prog\haskell\utils>ListArgs.exe '*'
["'*'"]

D:\Files\Andrew\prog\haskell\utils>ListArgs.exe '*
["'*"]

D:\Files\Andrew\prog\haskell\utils>ListArgs.exe -*
["-*"]
```

Comment: AndrewC, thank you for your answer, single quotes are really works in cmd.exe. However under cygwin it doesn't work, I still get list of files in current dir. -* works everywhere.

Comment: Using prefixes and single quotes is kind of workaround, and aren't obviously for user. Developer also should keep in mind such behavior in Windows, and somehow eliminate unwanted symbols from input. I'd prefer to have a function which doesn't make such substitutions. But seems Haskell platform doesn't provide such function. It's a pity.

Comment: I've not used cygwin in years. I'll add a tag to broaden the audience.